# Add an if statement to append()

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Is it possible to add an `if` statement to this `append()` inside a jQuery function ?

```
}).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    $(ul).addClass("quicksearch");
    $(ul).css('margin-left','-125px');
    var rating_color = item.level;
    var revision = item.revision.toLowerCase();

    //if revision === "") { append only !   

    return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append('<a><img class="clubpicture" src="'+item.clubpicture+'" /><img class="nationpicture" src="'+item.nationpicture+'" /><span class="name">'+item.name+'</span> ('+item.position+') <span class="rating '+rating_color+' '+revision+'">'+item.rating+'</span></a>').appendTo(ul);
};
```

If anyone could point me in the correct direction that'd be great

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could provide me with any directions as to where or how please ?

Comment: why not just return in the conditional as well as outside it? You worried about redundant code or something?

Comment: @KaiQing I don't know what that means, I'm an amateur here lol

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/v2dFg/)***

You could hook into jquery

```
$.fn.customIf = function(){
 var els = [];
 this.each(function(){
   if( this instanceof HTMLDivElement ){
    els.push(this);
   }
 });
 return $(els);
};
```

as an example. This would only send `<div>` elements on to be appended on to.

Comment: I sure do appreciate it your input, but that's completely blown my mind, Sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is what I mean in my comment:

```
function(ul, item) {
    $(ul).addClass("quicksearch");
    $(ul).css('margin-left','-125px');
    var rating_color = item.level;
    var revision = item.revision.toLowerCase();

    if(revision == "") { 
        return $("<li></li>").append('<a><img class="clubpicture" src="'+item.clubpicture+'" /><img class="nationpicture" src="'+item.nationpicture+'" /><span class="name">'+item.name+'</span> ('+item.position+') <span class="rating '+rating_color+' '+revision+'">'+item.rating+'</span></a>').appendTo(ul);
    }

    return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append('<a><img class="clubpicture" src="'+item.clubpicture+'" /><img class="nationpicture" src="'+item.nationpicture+'" /><span class="name">'+item.name+'</span> ('+item.position+') <span class="rating '+rating_color+' '+revision+'">'+item.rating+'</span></a>').appendTo(ul);
};
```

that would return the conditional before the other one fires. It's redundant but would do what you're asking. Keep in mind, the only difference between the two is the conditional one does not set the data item

Comment: That didn't seem to work, it's just still returning everything, thanks anyway

Comment: I didn't expect it to just drop in. THe principal is to return in the conditional. If it is returning everything, consider console.log(revision) to make sure it actually equals ""

Answer (score 0):

The following seem to worked for me, thanks to @kai-qing

```
function(ul, item) {
        $(ul).addClass("quicksearch");
        $(ul).css('margin-left','-125px');
        var rating_color = item.level;
        var revision = item.revision.toLowerCase();

        if(revision == "") { 
            return $("<li></li>").append('<a><img class="clubpicture" src="'+item.clubpicture+'" /><img class="nationpicture" src="'+item.nationpicture+'" /><span class="name">'+item.name+'</span> ('+item.position+') <span class="rating '+rating_color+' '+revision+'">'+item.rating+'</span></a>').appendTo(ul);
        }

        return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item);
});
```